# How to upload multiple images using codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

I'm trying to upload multiple image using codeigniter thats actually working fine, But I want to store images to specific directory.
My directory structure is

> uploads/real/

inside this directory I want to create one more directory with the name of userid so directory structure becomes

> uplods/real/20

I added logic and written some code like below: 
Consider $path="real", and $userid="20"

```
function image_upload($path,$userid)
    {
        $basepath = "uploads/".$path;
        echo "base-path > ".$basepath;
        echo "<br>working-dir > ".getcwd();
        chdir($basepath);
        echo "<br>working-dir > ".getcwd();
        if(!file_exists($userid)){
            mkdir($userid);
            chdir($userid);
            echo "<br>Working-dir > ".getcwd();
            $filesCount = count($_FILES['image']['name']);
            echo "<br> FileCount > ".$filesCount;
            for($i = 0; $i < $filesCount; $i++){
                $_FILES['img']['name'] = $_FILES['image']['name'][$i];
                $_FILES['img']['type'] = $_FILES['image']['type'][$i];
                $_FILES['img']['tmp_name'] = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][$i];
                $_FILES['img']['error'] = $_FILES['image']['error'][$i];
                $_FILES['img']['size'] = $_FILES['image']['size'][$i];

                echo "<br>FILES-Array > <pre>";
                print_r($_FILES);
                echo "<pre>";

                $config['upload_path']= "/";
                $config['file_name']=$userid .$i. '.jpg';
                $config['allowed_types']= 'jpg|png';
                $config['max_size']= 2048;

                echo "<br>CONFIG-Array > <pre>";
                print_r($config);
                echo "<pre>";

                $this->load->library('upload', $config);
                $this->upload->initialize($config);

                if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('img'))
                {
                    $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
                    echo "<br>UPLOAD-ERROR > <pre>";
                    print_r($error);
                    echo "<pre>";
                }
                else
                {
                    $da = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
                    echo "_________IMAGE UPLOADED_______";
                }
            }

        }else{
            echo "<br>Folder Exist ...";
        }
        die();
```

And Browser Output is :

```
base-path > uploads/real
working-dir > C:\wamp64\www\ob_03
working-dir > C:\wamp64\www\ob_03\uploads\real
Working-dir > C:\wamp64\www\ob_03\uploads\real\20
FileCount > 1
    FILES-Array >
Array
(
    [image] => Array
        (
            [name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => abhi.jpg
                )

            [type] => Array
                (
                    [0] => image/jpeg
                )

            [tmp_name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => C:\wamp64\tmp\php336F.tmp
                )

            [error] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                )

            [size] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 72125
                )

        )

    [img] => Array
        (
            [name] => abhi.jpg
            [type] => image/jpeg
            [tmp_name] => C:\wamp64\tmp\php336F.tmp
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 72125
        )

)
CONFIG-Array > 
Array
(
    [upload_path] => /
    [file_name] => 180.jpg
    [allowed_types] => jpg|png
    [max_size] => 2048
)
_________IMAGE UPLOADED_______
```

I'm not getting any error on printing `print_r($error);` But image is not uploaded to my directory WHY?

Comment: Might be happening because you are not telling it to! Can you see that you are setting your upload path to '/'. It says so in your code and also in your output.

Comment: When I set upload path to [upload_path] => uploads/real/18 I'm getting error from error array [error] => 
The upload path does not appear to be valid.

Comment: Do your paths get created when you use mkdir? Do they exist? Does your base folder have the correct permissions?

Comment: Yes path is created : The directory with userid 20 is created inside folder name 'real'

Comment: Well that being the case.. You are setting $config['upload_path']= "/"; Shouldn't that be the path you want to save your images in? ie the ones you are creating!

Comment: I want to upload my images to uploads/real/20 for user with userid 20, The path uploads/real/userid is created their, Im getting image uploaded message on echoing, But image is not uploaded to that directory

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128414/discussion-between-abhijit-kumbhar-and-timbrownlaw).

Comment: Try something like  `$config['upload_path']= './uploads/real/18/';` or  `$config['upload_path']=  FCPATH . 'uploads/real/18/'; ` make sure folder correct out side of application dir and set 0777 permission

Comment: I tried that getting error : [error] => 
The upload path does not appear to be valid.

Comment: Thats works. :)  FCPATH . 'uploads/real/18/'

Comment: @wolfgang1983 make answer to this question I want to accept your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `FCPATH` for uploads sometimes works better.

**FCPATH: Path to the front controller (this file) (root of CI)**

```
$config['upload_path'] = FCPATH . 'uploads/real/18/';
```

Or try

```
$config['upload_path'] = './uploads/real/18/';
```

Make sure you set 0777 for image uploads folders.